# Using Tuple field names in JSON responses

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, tuples

B"H

Is there a way to return field names when using Tuples as return types for actions?

What I would like to do is skip creating DTOs for every single function in every single controller. When I have a complex system with many controllers each with many actions (functions). I often find that there are a handful of central DTOs. Then there are hundreds of slight variations of them. One for each function. I would like to stick with the handful of central classes and skip the extra classes. Replacing them with Tuples.

For example. I have a Customer class

```
    public class Customer 
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
    }
```

with a many to many relation to store locations

```
    public class StoreLocation
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string City{ get; set; }
        public string State{ get; set; }
        public string Focus{ get; set; }
    }
```

I then have a function in a controller

```
    [HttpGet("TopCustomersByState")]
    public IEnumerable<(Customer customer, string state )> TopCustomersByState()
    {
    }
```

and a function

```
    [HttpGet("TopCustomersByFocus")]
    public IEnumerable<(Customer customer, string focus)> TopCustomersByState()
    {
    }
```

and a function

```
    [HttpGet("CustomersAndTotalMoneySpent")]
    public IEnumerable<(Customer customer, float moneySpent)> CustomersAndTotalMoneySpent()
    {
    }
```

### These function are all accessed from Javascript in the browser expecting JSON.

Until now, I'd make a separate class for each return type. This quickly gets out of hand.The solution that I present above in my examples **if it were to work** would be perfect.The issue is that the JSON being returned is

```
  {
    "item1": {
    },
    "item2": null
  }
```

instead of the property names `customer`, `moneySpent`, etc. as you'd expect.

Thank you

Comment: And what is the problem? What is it all about?

Comment: Instead of the json being created representing the Tuple with the proper properties. It's created with the names, "item1", "item2", etc.

Comment: That JSON output is expected. Tuple fields have no names. The "names" you see are compiler magic. The actual fields are called `Item1`, `Item2` etc. If you want short-hand notation, use records

Comment: `skip creating DTOs for every single function` you *are* creating DTOs for every function, even when you use tuples. What changes is the notation and where that DTO is defined

Comment: I hear you about the compiler magic. Wondering if there's a way around it. And as far as the Tuples being DTOs. Correct they are. If this would work, it would give me all of the benefits of DTOs without the code overhead and having them defined with the function signature makes for much cleaner, easier, more maintenable code

Comment: Thank you for rewriting my question. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put any return type of data at all if you want to make it generic. In any case it is converted to a json string. You can use an anonymous class for example

```
 [HttpGet("CustomersAndTotalMoneySpent")]
    public IActionResult CustomersAndTotalMoneySpent()
    {
         ... your code
      return Ok (new { Focus = focus, Customer = customer } );
   
      //or
         return Ok (new List<object> { { Focus = focus, Customer = customer} }); 
                     //or List<dynamic>
    }
```

Comment: I want type safety. I want swagger, and generated typescript, and everything else that comes along with type safety. I just don't want to spend the time creating hundreds of classes and the maintenance overhead that come along with it

Comment: @Rabbi "I want type safety." and "I just don't want to spend the time creating hundreds of classes"  eliminate each other.  You have to select  the one. But in this case I don't see any safety issue, since it is not an input parameters,  your API returns all data.  Pls next time decide what you really want  before posting the question.